How to avoid repetition between files.exclude, files.watcherExclude, and search.exclude settings?
My software project has a huge build folder and that makes my processor being at 100% all the time. I came across several settings that can be made at it solved my problem with the CPU. This is my .vscode/settings file:
{
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/build/**": true
    },
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/build/**": true
    },
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/build/**": true
    }
}

I have now to add about ten more exclude paths. Is the any way to simplifiy the settings so that I don't have to paste the ten paths for every *.exclude property?

search.exclude inherits by default from files.exclude, so you don't need to duplicate your files.exclude stuff in search.exclude.
files.watcherExclude does not inherit from anything (both according to documentation, and testing), so you may need to repeat yourself for that.
